# Experience Builder communication between map and my custom widget

Tags: arcgis-experience-builder, arcgis-custom-widget

I am working on a custom widget for Experience Builder which is my viewer (works as a standalone app). I need to communicate between my widget and the map.

I want to read the click on the map featurelayer properties in my widget and add options to the pop-up modal (which shows up when a user clicked an element on the map). These options are 'Add feature to my custom widget' and 'Add layer to my custom widget'.

I tried to use data-actions which as I understood are extra options in this pop-up modal but it doesn't show up in the pop-up.
In manifest.json I added:

```
"dataActions": [
    {
      "name": "Add item",
      "label": "add item",
      "uri": "data-actions/add-item"
    }
  ]
```

In src/runtime/translations/default.ts

```
export default {
    _widgetLabel: 'Add item',
    _action_additem_label: 'Add item'
}
```

In src/data-actions/add-item.ts

```
import { AbstractDataAction, type DataRecordSet, MutableStoreManager } from 'jimu-core'

export default class AddItem extends AbstractDataAction {
  async isSupported (dataSet: DataRecordSet): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log('dataSet ',dataSet);
    
    const { records } = dataSet
    return records?.length > 0
  }

  async onExecute (dataSet: DataRecordSet, actionConfig?: any): Promise<boolean> {
    //some code
    return true
  }
}
```

Do I miss sth?